# Set to Dictionary keyword from collections not accepting positional arguments

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using `set to dictionary` keyword from collections to put a key as `string` and value as a `list`, while doing this am getting error stating:

> Keyword `Collections.Set To Dictionary` got positional argument after named arguments.

I hope its stating that it won't accept a list as a value, I am new to this framework. I have a scenario to pass my test results as a list to some other function along with a key. Can anyone help me on this or provide a work around to achieve it. Please find my piece of code as below:

```
@{result_list}=    create list    ${TEST_NAME}    "User Should be logged in"    ${Actualresult}   ${Status}

set to dictionary    &{Test_result_dict}    ${tid}    ${result_list}
```

Please let me know if you need additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line:

```
set to dictionary    &{Test_result_dict}    ${tid}    ${result_list}
```

should be change to:

```
set to dictionary    ${Test_result_dict}    ${tid}    ${result_list}
```

So instead `&` you should use `$`. This means that you are referring the variable as a scalar instead of as a dictionary. Here is the relevant part of the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-variables).

The [Dictionary variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dictionary-variable-syntax) describes what is exactly the problem for you.

> **In practice this means that individual items of the dictionary are**
> **passed as named arguments to the keyword.** Assuming that a variable
> &{USER} has value {'name': 'robot', 'password': 'secret'}, the
> following two test cases are equivalent.
>
> ```
> *** Test Cases *** Constants
>     Login    name=robot    password=secret
>
> Dict Variable
>     Login    &{USER}
> ```

When you use `&` the elements of the dictionary are passed as named arguments, which proceeds the `${tid}` and `${result_list}` variables resulting "positional argument after named arguments" error.

When you use `$` the dictionary itself will be passed.